# Make partials in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a ruby on rails app and I have rather big controllers.

Now I have the same actions to be done on a create action and a delete action so I was wandering if it's possible to make this DRY. Or is this only possible with views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this:

1. Move all model related code to your models and call model actions on models in your controller. This is a great way to clean up your controller especially if you are querying the model for generic things.
2. Create private actions in your controller to reduce duplication of code.
3. You can create methods inside a module and import the module into your controller. This should reduce the size of your controller as well as making it DRY (you could even reuse that module in different controllers).

   ```
   module MyModule
       def my_method
       end
   end

   # in controller
   include MyModule
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can only create partials in view.
Code repeatation in controller can be made DRY by writing the similar part of code as a method in Model and calling it in as many actions in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In `rails4` had a folder which called `concern`, you can use `concern` to split your code in controller.

You can refer about concern at: [concern](http://elegantbrew.tumblr.com/post/70990048275/controller-concerns-in-rails-4)